# Ubuntu wired network suddenly stopped working

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ethernet

Ubuntu 17.04. I don't have enough experience with it to know what to do about this.
updates were installed yesterday, today after connecting to the docking station the wired network doesn't work anymore. I noticed a problem when the wired network related entries in the network menu in the upper right were gone. wireless still works.

I tried a couple of things, one of which may have been a mistake. I deleted the ethernet connection in the Network Connections dialog to try to recreate it. I did. before though this network connection (Ethernet connection 1) had a value in the Device field on the Ethernet tab, it had what looked like a mac address. now however with the new one there is nothing, and the drop down has no entries in it to select. I hope I didn't make the problem worse by doing this.

its like eth0 just vanished over night. it had been working fine for months.

output of sudo lshw -C network shows an entry for the network, so something still sees it. output:

```
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
   vendor: Broadcom Limited
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
   logical name: wlp12s0
   version: 01
   serial: [serial]
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=[ip address] latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:17 memory:f1ffc000-f1ffffff
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: NetXtreme BCM5761e Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
   vendor: Broadcom Limited
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
   version: 10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f1be0000-f1beffff memory:f1bf0000-f1bfffff
```

Much appreciated if anyone can please help me get it working again.